# Как писать Service слой?

Tags: java, crud

Я пишу CRUD приложение и столкнулся с проблемой, мне надо написать Service слой, но как это сделать я не могу найти нормальный материал. ДАО слой я уже написал, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Напишите в вопросе какую библиотеку использовали, хорошо будет если и пример вашей попытки добавите

Comment: Еще не пытался, просто определения понятные, что делает дао слой и сервис слой, но вот если дао конкретно понятно что писать надо, то для сервиса возникают трудности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаете интерфейс, обычно его называют по имени сущности, например `userService`. В данном интерфейсе лежат все Ваши методы, которые будут имплементированы в service-слое. Потом создаете класс, имплементирующий этот интерфейс, обычно его называют `userServiceImpl`. В этом классе создаете соответствующий экземпляр объекта, например `@Autowired userDAO userDao;`
Потом, с использованием данного объекта, реализуете свои сервис-методы.
Детальнее гляньте например тут: [https://github.com/Flibberty-GEA/blog/wiki/06-Сервис-слой](https://github.com/Flibberty-GEA/blog/wiki/06-%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: Благодарю. Получается сервис методы должны выполнять запрос от пользователя, используя дао слой?

Comment: Своеобразная обертка, которая "не знает" о деталях реализации методов в слое dao